# Why is my python aes-ctr-128 micro benchmark with block by block encryption slow?

Tags: python, aes, microbenchmark

I designed an puzzle algorithm to take the value of each encrypted block which point to the next block to be encrypted. I have to use aes-ctr-128 for that with some particular reason.

I run a dummy test to see how fast or slow it could be.

Here is what I did. I tested both pycrypto and cryptography.

I first create a 16MB file with random bytes.

I tried in two ways:

**Method 1.** Load the file into a block list with block size 128bits.

**Method 2.** Simply load the file into a string.

Now I tested the total time to encrypt each 128-bit block. And I tested the total time to encrypt the whole file.

Here’s the result:

> pycrypto:
>
> 1. to encrypt 128-bit block one by one: 61,824 aes-ctr-128 per sec
> 2. to encrypt the entire file: 8,843,713 aes-ctr-128 per sec
>
> cryptography
>
> 1. to encrypt 128-bit block one by one: 384,959 aes-ctr-128 per sec
> 2. to encrypt the entire file: 113,417,922 aes-ctr-128 per sec

I'm wondering why method 1 and 2 gave me the result with so much difference? Are these two methods suppose to give the same speed?

Here's my test code:

```
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
backend = default_backend()

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util import Counter
import random
import time

BLOCK_SIZE = 16

def read_block(fname):
    block_list = []
    blobfo = open(fname)
    atEOF = False
    while not atEOF:
        blobdata = blobfo.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
        block_list.append(blobdata)
        if len(blobdata) < BLOCK_SIZE:
        # we should stop after this...
        atEOF = True
    return block_list


print 'loading data'
block_list = read_block('mediumdata')

print 'loading finish'
print len(block_list), 'blocks'

print 'start encryption'
NUM_COUNTER_BITS = 128
# Here I just use a random key
key = os.urandom(16)
t1 = time.time()
for block in block_list:
    ctr = Counter.new(NUM_COUNTER_BITS)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
    cipher.encrypt(block)
t2 = time.time()
print 'finish encryption'

print 'total time:', t2 - t1
print 'time for each aes:', (t2 - t1) / len(block_list)

print 'num of aes per sec:', len(block_list) / (t2 - t1)

print 'now try to encrypt whole file'
block = open('mediumdata').read()
print type(block)
print 'start encryption'
NUM_COUNTER_BITS = 128
key = os.urandom(16)
t1 = time.time()
ctr = Counter.new(NUM_COUNTER_BITS)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
cipher.encrypt(block)
t2 = time.time()
print 'finish encryption'

print 'total time:', t2 - t1
print 'time for each aes:', (t2 - t1) / len(block_list)

print 'num of aes per sec:', len(block_list) / (t2 - t1)


print 'now try cryptography'

print 'start encryption'
t1 = time.time()
num = random.randint(1, 65530)
nonce = "".join(chr((num >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF) for i in range(16))
backend = default_backend()
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CTR(nonce), backend=backend)
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
for block in block_list:
    ciphertext = encryptor.update(block)
encryptor.finalize()
t2 = time.time()
print 'finish encryption'

print 'total time:', t2 - t1
print 'time for each aes:', (t2 - t1) / len(block_list)

print 'num of aes per sec:', len(block_list) / (t2 - t1)

print 'try a whole file'

block = open('mediumdata').read()

print 'start encryption'
t1 = time.time()
num = random.randint(1, 65530)
nonce = "".join(chr((num >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF) for i in range(16))
backend = default_backend()
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CTR(nonce), backend=backend)
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
ciphertext = encryptor.update(block)# + encryptor.finalize()
encryptor.finalize()
t2 = time.time()
print 'finish encryption'


print 'total time:', t2 - t1
print 'time for each aes:', (t2 - t1) / len(block_list)

print 'num of aes per sec:', len(block_list) / (t2 - t1)
```

Did I miss anything here?

Is there a way that I can make method 1 faster?

Comment: encryptions are tend to be slow, I dont think you can  get same speed

Comment: @YOU Is method 1 supposed to get the same speed as method 2?

Comment: @YOU Encryption speed depends on the device, it does not have to be slow. An iPhone6S performs at 400+ MB/s.

Comment: Clarify what is "method 1 and 2"? Comparing pycrypto to cryptography or block-by-block to all-at-once? Does "61,824 aes-ctr-128 per sec" mean "61,824 bytes per second?

Comment: @zaph Method 1 is to encrypt every 128-bit of the file one by one. Method 2 is to load the entire file and call an encryption for it.

Comment: I guess the slow down is due to frequent "context switch" between the crypto environment and Python interpreter.

Comment: Method 1 is making 1,000,000 more function calls, that is more time expensive than just indexing into an array.

Comment: @kennytm I also suspect that this is due to python GIL(global interpreter lock ). Since a 128-bit encrypt should be cost really a tiny time in C, maybe the interval between release and acquire of the GIL is much longer than the encryption itself. Thus the wast of switch time cause the problem. However, I have no proof of this.

Answer (score 2):

AES is a block cipher with multiple permutation rounds. Each round has it's own round key, which needs to be derived from "master" key (`key` in your code). Calling `AES.new(key, mode, ...)` will automatically derive the round keys, but this *key schedule* process is quite heavy. Doing the key schedule for every block will slow down the processing considerably considerably compared to the one-call approach, especially if the actual encryption code uses the AES-NI instruction set.

Additionally, as kennytm points out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356896/why-my-python-aes-ctr-128-micro-benchmark-with-one-by-one-encryption-is-slow/37360986#comment62231913_37356896), Python is an interpreted language, so iterating over the blocks in Python instead of the underlying native crypto code (e.g. pyCrypto uses the C library tomcrypt) will necessarily incur an additional performance penalty.

---

The code for Method 1 is broken, because you're creating a new Counter object for each block, which is always initialized to `1`. Thus, you're XORing every block with the same key stream, which creates a [many-time pad](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25299/13022) and likely enables an attacker to deduce the plaintext.

We can fix this by only having a single Counter object. Having also a single key schedule considerably increases the performance.

Improved Method 1 code:

```
ctr = Counter.new(NUM_COUNTER_BITS)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
for block in block_list:
    cipher.encrypt(block)
```

Results for pyCrypto:

```
1049887 blocks

Method 1
total time: 17.31999993324279785156
time for each aes: 1.64970134245e-05
num of aes per sec: 60617.0325662

Improved Method 1
total time: 0.78299999237060546875
time for each aes: 7.45794540146e-07
num of aes per sec: 1340851.86492

Method 2
total time: 0.147000074387
time for each aes: 1.4001513914e-07
num of aes per sec: 7142084.82126
```

[**Full code**](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/e65680ce7d1d8284670cbe56afec814b)

Comment: I don't have any experience with the `cryptography` module, so my guess would be that either the iteration is in python is a big problem or it has a bug in it.

Comment: It make sense that there is a cost for each Counter object is  initialized. So in Method 1, each time when I create a new Counter object, the cost adds up. I have two questions. 1. Method 2 also need to update the Counter value by 1 for each 128-bit block, why it is faster? Is it because it's just an update instead of creating a new Counter object?

Comment: 2. In my real-life implementation, according to my design, the Counter value for the next 128-bit depends on the encryption output for the previous 128-bit. In this manner, is there a way that I can only update the Counter value but not initialize a new Counter object? Thanks for your help.

Comment: To be more clear, when I have the encryption output for the first 128-bit block, I use this output to decide which block is the next to encrypt and what the Counter value should be. It is different from directly take the next piece of block in the file and encrypt it. It's more likely a pointer jumping encryption.

Comment: Re 1: Yes, the cost of the Counter adds up, but that is not what is slow here. AES is a block cipher that needs a key schedule. If the key doesn't change for multiple blocks (as is the case for CTR mode), the key schedule can be executed once and not for each block again and again. `AES.new(...)` executes the key schedule, so it will be slow if it is done again and again.

Comment: Re 2: It sounds to me like you want to implement CBC mode. Anyway, in that case, you should not use the `counter` argument, but rather the `nonce` argument and pass in your custom counter value inside of the loop, but then you also lose the advantage of running the key schedule only once. You should look into using ECB mode as a basis to simulate your custom mode of operation. I don't know if one can use a custom Counter class, because it is implemented in C.